# programmatically adding product to cart returns empty price

Tags: magento-1.8, product, php, cart

i have been trying to programmatically add a product to cart using following lines of code, it seems to work and successfully adds product but for some reason, the price of newly added product always sets to zero.. how can i prevent this and let the actual price of product to be set for cart?

```
<?php

 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once("app/Mage.php");
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');



 function mres($value)
{
    $search = array("\\",  "\x00", "\n",  "\r",  "'",  '"', "\x1a");
    $replace = array("\\\\","\\0","\\n", "\\r", "\'", '\"', "\\Z");

    return str_replace($search, $replace, $value);
}


echo "testing";
print_r($_POST);



$fname = mres( $_POST['fname'] );
$lname = mres( $_POST['lname'] );
$email = mres( $_POST['email'] );
$day = mres( $_POST['day'] );
$month = mres( $_POST['month'] );
$year = mres( $_POST['year'] );
$phone = mres( $_POST['phone'] );
$mobile = mres( $_POST['mobile'] );
$city = mres( $_POST['city'] );
$address = mres( $_POST['address'] );
$discount = mres( $_POST['discount'] );
$quantity = mres( $_POST['quantity'] );
$comments = mres( $_POST['comments'] );
$url = mres( $_POST['url'] );
$store = mres( $_POST['store'] );
$store_id = mres( $_POST['store_id'] );
$web_id = mres( $_POST['web_id'] );
$product_id = mres( $_POST['product_id'] );
$sku = mres( $_POST['sku'] );

setcookie('fname', $fname);
setcookie('lname', $lname);
setcookie('email', $email);
//setcookie('age', $age);
setcookie('phone', $phone);
setcookie('mobile', $mobile);
setcookie('city', $city);
setcookie('address', $address);



$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
//$customer  = new Mage_Customer_Model_Customer();
$password = substr(str_shuffle(md5(time())),0,8);;

$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
$customer->loadByEmail($email);


//Zend_Debug::dump($customer->debug()); 

$isNew = 0;
if(!$customer->getId()) {
    $customer->setEmail($email);
    $customer->setFirstname($fname);
    $customer->setLastname($lname);
    $customer->setPassword($password);
    $isNew = 1;
}
try {
    $customer->save();
    $customer->setConfirmation(null);
    $customer->save();

    if($isNew)
    {
        $customer->sendNewAccountEmail();


        $ch = curl_init();

        //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, "//sameurl.php");
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($_POST));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);

        //execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        //close connection
        curl_close($ch);


    }

    Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginById($customer->getId());
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
    //Zend_Debug::dump($ex->getMessage());
}





//Build billing and shipping address for customer, for checkout
$_custom_address = array (
    'firstname' => $fname,
    'lastname' => $lname,
    'street' => array (
        '0' => $address,
        '1' => '',
    ),
    'city' => $city,
    'region_id' => '',
    'region' => '',
    'postcode' => '0000',
    'country_id' => 'PK',
    'telephone' => $phone . '-' . $mobile,
);
//$customAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address')
$customAddress = new Mage_Customer_Model_Address();
$customAddress->setData($_custom_address)
            ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
            ->setIsDefaultBilling('1')
            ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
            ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');
try {
    $customAddress->save();


    Zend_Debug::dump($customAddress->debug()); 


}
catch (Exception $ex) {
    Zend_Debug::dump($ex->getMessage());
}
//Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->setBillingAddress(Mage::getSingleton('sales/quote_address')->importCustomerAddress($customAddress));


Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()
->setBillingAddress(Mage::getSingleton('sales/quote_address')->importCustomerAddress($customAddress)) ->setShippingAddress(Mage::getSingleton('sales/quote_address')->importCustomerAddress($customAddress));

/*
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', $sku)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->getFirstItem();

$product->load($product_id);
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');

$productInstance = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$cart->truncate();
$cart->save();
$cart->getItems()->clear()->save();
try {
    //$cart->addProduct($product, array('options'=> array('some-custom-option-id-here' => 'Some value goes here');
    //$cart->addProduct($product, array('price' => 5000));
    //$cart->addProduct($productInstance, $param);
    //$cart->save();


    $cart->init();
    $cart->addProduct($product, array('qty' => $qty));
    $cart->save();
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);


}
catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
unset($product);
*/

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', $sku)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->getFirstItem();

$product->load($product_id);
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$quote->addProduct($product, $qty);

$quote->collectTotals()->save();


$storeId = $store_id;
$checkout = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage');
$checkout->initCheckout();
$checkout->saveCheckoutMethod('register');
$checkout->saveShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate');     
$checkout->savePayment(array('method'=>'free'));


try {
    $checkout->saveOrder();
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
/* Clear the cart */
$cart->truncate();
$cart->save();
$cart->getItems()->clear()->save();
/* Logout the customer you created */
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->logout();


?>
```

Comment: Where/how is `$product` defined?

Comment: i have edit the question and product definition is at top, i have also tried $productInstance which is up there too but still no dice

Comment: i have updated question with full code so far, its bit messy but you can get some idea what i am trying to do...

Comment: can  you tell why you clear cart in last step..

Comment: @AmitBera i have removed those lines... it was somehow helpful too..

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are many things wrong here and I feel compelled to do a code review with you. **See the end for the correct approach.**

## Code review:

---

**This line is loading a product with an undefined $sku var:**

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', $sku)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->getFirstItem();
```

**Now you're reloading the $product var with an undefined value, returns a blank model or null.**

```
$product->load($product_id);
```

**Getting the cart model (but not necessarily mine from my customer session):**

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
```

**Wait - now we're loading another instance of a blank object:**

```
$productInstance = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
```

**Clearing the brand new cart:**

```
$cart->truncate();
```

**Saving our empty cart:**

```
$cart->save();
```

**Getting all the items in our empty cart, clearing them, and saving again:**

```
$cart->getItems()->clear()->save();
```

## The right way:

---

All in all this code makes no sense. Some Google searching turns up the right way to add a product to the current user's cart with the correct price attached:

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$quote->addProduct($product, $qty);

$quote->collectTotals()->save();
```

Where `$product` and `$qty` are both defined, and `$product` is an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` and `$qty` is an integer.

Comment: i am getting this:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Varien_Exception' with message 'Invalid method Mage_Checkout_Model_Session::addProduct(Array ( [0] => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product Object......
  probably there is no method addProduct here $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session'); $quote->addProduct($product, $qty);

Comment: secondly i am using onepage checkout!

Comment: $storeId = $store_id;
$checkout = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage');
$checkout->initCheckout();
$checkout->saveCheckoutMethod('register');
$checkout->saveShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate');  
$checkout->savePayment(array('method'=>'free'));


try {
    $checkout->saveOrder();
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
/* Clear the cart */
$cart->truncate();
$cart->save();
$cart->getItems()->clear()->save();
/* Logout the customer you created */
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->logout();

Comment: @ehmad11,are doing outside magento... or in magento frontend area??

Comment: it's outside magento....

Comment: @ehmad11 you're right I missed one part. See my updated.

Comment: it seems to work now but sill price sets to 0...

Comment: Then the issue lies entirely on your side. Disable all local modules and revert to the default theme. Follow the standard debug process: https://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-debug-process/

Comment: i am trying this on fresh installation without any theme or module...

Comment: @ehmad11 what is the update on this?

Comment: i have been trying all this, still price sets to zero for no reason :(

Comment: i used 'quote' thing; changed payment method and removed last lines that were 'clearing cart'... it's working now!

Comment: just one last thing, how should i clear the cart before i add product?

Comment: is it safe to use 
$quote->delete(); 
before 
$quote->addProduct($product, $qty);  
?

Comment: When there is a quote pending payment, it would not be able to `addProduct()` and normal checkout steps would not acquire that quote, thus view will be redirect to an empty cart. I guess the most appropriate way should be `Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->addProduct()`, this way a new quote will be created on-demand.

Comment: hey @philwinkle thanks .. The code `$quote->collectTotals()->save();` save my one month works

Answer (score 3):

Here we add the product to cart using external script

```
<?php
include 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
// Need for start the session
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
try {
    $product_id = '52'; // Replace id with your product id
    $qty = '4'; // Replace qty with your qty
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
    $cart->init();
    $cart->addProduct($product, array('qty' => $qty));
    $cart->save();
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Product added successfully');
    header('Location: ' . 'index.php/checkout/cart/');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

**Note**:- here **52** is the simple product-id and **4** is the quantity value, you can replace with your quantity.

Comment: I want to first clear cart and than add to cart. How can i do

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before.
In my task, I needed to add product on specific quote.Below code helped me to accomplish this:

```
$quoteModel = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId);
$cartModel = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$cartModel->setData('quote', $quoteModel);
$cartModel->init();
$cartModel->addProduct(productId, array('qty'=>5));
$cartModel->save();
```

Hope that wil help you in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the easy way to add product to cart/quote:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
// load quote by customer and store...
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStore($storeId)->loadByCustomer($customerId);
$quote->addProduct($product, 1);
$quote->setIsActive(1);
$quote->collectTotals()->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code to add product to Cart:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
// load quote by customer and store...
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStore($storeId)->loadByCustomer($customerId);
$quote->addProduct($product, 1);
$quote->setIsActive(1);
$quote->collectTotals()->save();
```